# Broken toilet flange

Tags: plumbing

[image: Toilet flange]

I picked up my toilet because it was leaking and found out that one side of the flange is broken. Is there anything I can do to fix this?

Comment: You need to do some cleaning up so we can see what's there. What type of construction? first floor? second floor?  Access  to plumbing below, etc.  floor material.

Comment: Call a plumber.

Comment: Do you have access underneath the bathroom to see what the state of the sub-floor is around the toilet? As other have said - it could be very rotted, depending on how long the leak has been ongoing. I bought a little house a few years ago where the only reason the toilet hadn't fallen through the floor was because it was being held up by the cast-iron drain pipe directly underneath it - the floor was rotted out a good 3-6" all around the flange.

Answer (score 5):

Big box Home repair stores, Hardware and plumbing supply stores sell stainless repair rings that can be screwed over a damaged flange. That is supposing the floor is not rotted.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the wax and the retainer ring (the rotten metal thing) to properly assess the damage to the floor.

From this photo it looks like the sub floor is damaged (rotten) = big job.

To test, use a Philips screwdriver and poke. If it is rotten it will go deep.

Depending on your DYI capability you could do it yourself.

Depending on the photo, you will need a plumber, who needs to replace rotten sub floor.

The repair process (for rotten floor):

Cut the sub floor about 16 inches wide (3/4 inch deep), til you reach the support beams than place new 3/4 inch sub floor. Cut the toilet hole in right position. Mount new retainer ring, insert wax ring and mount the toilet without over tightening the toilet screws (which lead to crack in first place).